# Filter Reflection, cs50 - What is wrong with the code? More info regarding my question in comments

Tags: c, cs50

```c
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    temp_array temp[width];
    
    int row;
    
    for (row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[j].red = image[row][j].rgbtRed;
            temp[j].green = image[row][j].rgbtGreen;
            temp[j].blue = image[row][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            image[row][i].rgbtRed = temp[width - i].red;
            image[row][i].rgbtGreen = temp[width - i].green;
            image[row][i].rgbtBlue = temp[width - i].blue;
        }
    }
return;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I am doing this pset4 for cs50 and i am currently on the part of "Reflection".

I have come up with a solution that seemingly works, but i returns error when running check50. Why?

Ofcourse, my code probably isnt very beautifully designed, but it returns the reflected output on all tested photos as should be, but still isnt passing check50.    
     
I made a typedef struct to store the temp pixel colours, and then i put them in again in the reversed order.    
   
 typedef struct
    {
        BYTE red;
        BYTE green;
        BYTE blue;
    }
    temp_array;

Comment: "but i returns error when running check50. Why?" Because one or more specific test cases fail. If you look at the test case, the expected output and the wrong output, you should be able to feed the same data into your program and step through a debuffer.

Comment: Why would you create a new `typedef`? Ther is a type for exactly that purpose: `RGBTRIPLE` Use that.

Comment: Some hints: `temp[width - i]` What range does that index have in that loop? What range will it have in the loop where you set values to `temp`? What range is valid for your array definition? Also for swapping 2 pixels you should not make a copy of a whole row but just use 1 single temp variable. BTW: You can assign the whole struct in one assignment. No need to assign each field separately.

Comment: And finally: Please add your text from comment to the post.

Comment: Thanks! ill give it try, and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: "but it returns the reflected output on all tested photos as should be" No, it doesn't. Look closely!

Comment: First time i use stack overflow. I dont understand how to use it yet haha. When i tried putting the text on the post, it wants me to edit and enter code. Didnt understand how to work around it.

Comment: im sure you are right about that it isnt the same somewhere, but i havent succeeded to find where it is not exactly the same. Ive spent some time to look very closely, and failed to see a difference.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an off-by-1 issue in your loop to copy the pixels.
I simplyfied it a bit for demonstration purposes.

```c
       RGBTRIPLE *current_row = image[row];
       for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
       {
           temp[j].red = current_row[j].rgbtRed;
       }
    
       for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
       {
           current_row[i].rgbtRed = temp[width - i].red;
       }
```

You copy `row[0]` into `temp[0]`. Same for all elements up to `width-1`;

Then you copy `temp[width-0]` into `row[0]`. But your array `temp` does not contain an element `width` as it only has elements `0 .. width-1`.
The pixel should be taken from `row[width - 1 - i]` instead.
That will avoid shifting the pixels by 1 position during copying.
It will also avoid accessing your array beyond its maximum limit which causes undefined behaviour.

Besides that your code is rather inefficient. You are consuming way too much memory.
Your task is to swap pixels. For swapping something you should not need more than 1 element in most cases. Not an arra to store a whole row.

Also don't invent new types for things that already exist. You swap pixels of type `RGBTRIPLE`. Use that type. Don't add another type to re-invent the wheel.

For swapping a pixel just use this:

```c
           RGBTRIPLE temp = image[row][j];
           image[row][j] = image[row][width-1-j];
           image[row][width-1-j] = temp;
```

Then remove all the unused types, arrays and loops.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the help! i went with doing the swapfunction instead.